# How To Create A Structure With Nested Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Photo of Firestore Document structure:

[image: Photo of Firestore Document structure]

I am trying to use a structure to create a data model that will show my data from Firestore. But I'm a bit confused on how to get my mapped/nested data. I'm sure its something simple but I feel like I'm missing the fundamentals of something about Swift. My code is below and I'm pretty sure what I have to retrieve the first and last name is wrong. I understand how to get surface level data via the same way but when its an array or mapped I can't seem to understand the syntax.

```
protocol DocumentSerializable  {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}
struct ItemModel{

    var merchant: String?
    var first: String?
    var last: String?

    
    var dictionary:[String:Any]{
        return [
            "merchant":
                ["first": first,
                 "last": last
                ]
        ]
    }
}
extension ItemModel : DocumentSerializable { 
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) { 
       guard let merchant = dictionary["merchant"] as? String,
       let first = dictionary["first"] as? String,
       let last = dictionary["last"] as? String 
       else {return nil}
self.init(merchant:merchant, first:first, last:last)}}
```

Comment: According to the screenshot `Merchant` is the model with keys `first`, `last` and `timestamp`

Comment: Exactly. I’m not sure if I have the reflected in my dictionary especially in the self.init

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary has Key : "merchant" and value : ["first": first, "last": last], so the "merchant" variable below is a dictionary and to access this below makes sense:

```
extension ItemModel : DocumentSerializable { 
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) { 
       guard let merchant = dictionary["merchant"] as? Dictionary,
       let first = merchant["first"] as? String,
       let last = merchant["last"] as? String 
       else {return nil}
     self.init(merchant:"merchant", first:first, last:last)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot it looks like merchant is a separate object and timestamp is a separate key.

```
struct ItemModel {
      var merchant: Merchant
      var timestamp: Double
}
```

And the merchant struct as

```
struct Merchant {
     var first:String?
     var last:String?
}
```

This makes the ItemModel have the structure as given in the screenshot